# How do I turn on line numbering in Meld diff viewer?

Tags: linux, meld

I can't find the option to enable line numbering. It'd be very helpful!

Comment: Nevermind, I hovered over the grayed-out option and it said to install gnome-python-desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just believe it needs other dependencies, I saw them on Meld homepage but they are optional. On Fedora, try this

```
yum install gtksourceview
yum install gnome-python2-gtksourceview
yum install gnome-python2-gnomeprint
```

Comment: Outdated answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem on Ubuntu and just to spare another unobservant person the time I spent digging around for it I thought I'd add an answer here as well.

If you go into preferences you can see that the option to show line numbers is grayed out but if you hover over it it says to install python-gtksourceview2.

So on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gtksourceview2
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: Outdated answer.

Answer (score 4):

The previous [answer](https://superuser.com/a/816514/390786) said to go into preferences within Meld. However, I can't see any preferences menu entry, which is consistent with the following [post](https://linux.m2osw.com/no-meld-preferences-menu) I found that proposed a solution with `dconf-editor` to toggle line numbers on/off.

Steps:

1. Open `dconf-editor`
2. Navigate to the path `org.gnome.meld`
3. Toggle the setting for line numbers:

[image: dconf-editor screenshot]

For me, on Ubuntu 18.04, I didn't need to install any additional dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else comes across it and since the answers are quite old:

[image: meld show line number]

also works on the Windows installation